# Error getting Ninject and WebApi v1 (MVC4) to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, architecture, dependency-injection, ninject

This is the error message I get:

```
  "Type 'GDMServices.Controllers.DmpeController' does not have a default constructor",
```

I started going down this path as the answer appeared to work for a couple of users but I started getting errors that made me think something has changed and abandoned that solution. One of the errors was the inability to resolve IRequest, even after I added a reference to System.Web.Http.Services (which I thought was a MVC3 dependency).

[Ninject and ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652862/ninject-and-asp-net-web-api)

I saw a couple examples using unity but I really want to stick with Ninject.

Controller:

```
public class DmpeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly Logger _logger;
    private readonly IDmpeService dmpeService;

    public DmpeController(Logger logger, IDmpeService service)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
        this.dmpeService = service;
    }

    .....
```

In the App_Start folder, the NinjectWebCommons.cs generated from the nuget install:

```
//The class is untouched from generated form except the RegisterServices method where I added my bindings:

  private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IAppSettings>().To<AppSettings>();
        kernel.Bind<IDmpeService>().To<DmpeService>();
    }
```

[Update] One more note, I'm stuck with .Net 4.0 so I can't upgrade any of the packages.

So I'm back to trying the above referenced fix and the issue with IRequest remains, "The type or namespace name 'IRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\dev\git-repo\GDM.Data\GDMServices\Services\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs". I installed Ninject.MVC3 as prescribed to no avail.

```
public class NinjectScope : IDependencyScope
{
    protected IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;
    public NinjectScope(IResolutionRoot kernel)
    {
        resolutionRoot = kernel;
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return resolutionRoot.Resolve(request).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return resolutionRoot.Resolve(request).ToList();
    }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is right, but your `DmpeController` depends on `Logger` and you're not registering that dependency. Please, update your `RegisterServices` to register that dependency, and it will work.

I suppose NInject can handle concrete types registering and resolution. If that's not possible, extract the `ILogger` interface, and make the constructor depend on `ILogger` instead of depending on the concrete type `Logger`.